# SSH asks for passphrase three times and authenticates no matter what is entered

Tags: ssh, authentication, private-key, linode

When I attempt to SSH into a remote Linode server while using public key/private key and authentication, I'm asked to enter the key passphrase three times before it authenticates, and asks me the user password.

Strangely, I can enter anything when prompted for the key passphrase, and it will authenticate. If I enter nothing instead, I'm immediately prompted for the user password, basically bypassing the key passphrase in both situations.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Simplest fix is to completely disable password authentication

Comment: The `passphrase` is what is associated with the RSA key uses. The `password` is a separate authentication method completely.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you are getting confused between a passphrase and password.

SSH has multiple different mechanisms of authenticating, and tries each one in turn.   In this case it is trying to use public/private key encryption (where you are being asked for your passphrase) and then if that fails - which is happening here - it will fall back to password authentication.

You have a private key on your client (it will be in a file id_rsa).  If you enter it wrong multiple times - or don't have it - it will skip to the next authentication mechanism which is password.

**My guess is your passphrase is protected by a "enter" key or something similarly trivial.   If this is the case you will want to change the passphrase on your private key - which you can likely do with 'ssh-keygen' -p**